# Minimizing area of a triangle containing data points in 3D plane

Tags: matlab, 3d, computational-geometry, minimization

I have a set of data in 3D which are in the same plane. I have a Triangle containing those data points in the same plane. But the Area of the Triangle is much larger. I want to find the  smallest area triangle (co-ordinate of its 3 points) containing all the data point inside it. There are some concepts available for 2D data points, but I need to find this in 3D dimension.

Comment: Why would this be any different in 3D space? You are already operating under the assumption that a triangle can be used to represent all of these points. That means that they must all exist in the same plane, so you can toss out the irrelevant 3rd dimension and work with the data in 2D. Then, when you have the optimal 2D coordinates you can plug them into the plane equation to compute the missing 3rd.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Matlab has a function for this, `convhull`. You want to find the convex hull of the data set. http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/convhull.html This function works for points in 2d or 3d space.

Comment: This wont necessarily give you a triangle.

Comment: Yes, it looks like I missed that part of the question. This probably wouldn't give a triangle.

Comment: Thanks all for your answers. I am sorry that I am replying after a long time as I have not been here for a while.